# Implement custom connection pool?

Tags: java, concurrency, connection, connection-pooling

I was wondering if I need to implement my own connection pool, what will be high level algorithm?

I had a glance over couple of solutions(below links) on google but all of them looks not scalable to me. When i say scalable
I mainly focus on `getConnection()/borrowConnection()` method where i need to ensure if multiple threads calls this method at
same time, they don't get same connection and also wait is minimal. All of the below solution uses the synchronized method/block approach
which is not scalable at all  as in application like ecommerce threads has to wait.

1. https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40005/connection-pool-implementation
2. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076690/java-concurrency/build-your-own-objectpool-in-java-to-boost-app-speed.html
3. https://sridharrao85.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/sample-connection-pool-implementation/
4. http://www.javamadesoeasy.com/2015/12/connection-pooling-in-java-with-example.html

**Mine Solution :-** Basically my approach focus on how i can reduce the concurrency at granular level instead at data structure holding
the pool of connection. So i will keep two list(arralylist)

1. ConnectionsNotInUse
2. ConnectionInUse

ConnectionsNotInUse will hold all connections(wrapped in custom connection class) in pool at startup. Now if a thread asks for connection, once it gets it successfully , it will remove it from ConnectionsNotInUse and put it in ConnectionsInUse.

Inside each custom connection class, there will be method getConnection() method  which will use `Semaphore.tryAcquire()`  which Acquires a lock, if one is available and returns immediately, with the value true. It will be semaphore with one permit. So if thread does not get connection , it will loop over for another connection in list.

If at last if thread does not get any connection, it will create another connection if max permissible limit allows otherwise it will wait to be connection to be released.
Once connection is released , it notify the threads waiting for connection

Any comments/suggestions on approach suggested ?

Comment: You're suggesting here that connections are acquired so fast that synchronizing is too expensive -- what kind of network do you have then (which will use that connection) that will be faster than thread synchronisation on the same CPU?  In other words, are you sure that it will be a bottleneck?

Comment: @john16384 it will be a bottleneck for sure. Consider ecommerce website where million of request trying to acquire connection at same time. With method/block synchronization each request has to run in sequential manner.

Comment: Your site may need to serve a million requests at a time, but there is no Java VM that can handle a million threads at a time.  Most scalable setups will handle like max 1000 threads (usually lower) and queue the rest.  Further scaling is then achieved by load balancing over multiple instances.

Comment: @john16384 Agreed . Even consider 500 request  trying to acquire connection at same time. With method/block synchronization each request has to run in sequential manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your description:

the original implementation of the connection pool is like a room with only one entrance and only one person (thread) is allow to get in. What you are worried is person will line up in the entrance and influence the scalability of your app. So you decide to have multiple entrances (free list). But you seems not specify which entrance they should try, I assume you to let them try the first. If first is not available, they will try next entrance.

So if my understand is right, the policy which entrance they choose is the core of performance. If they all try first, then second, it will make little difference with original implementation.

What I can think about the fast and no sync way is to hash the identity of the person. If the resulted entrance is not free any more, there would be two ways:

- find next

  - hash again
  - next position, etc
- create new

---

So move back from metaphor. 
What I described is like the implementation of a hashmap and you may try it in two ways:

- replace your list with hashmap
- use a single map mixed with used and free connection, in which case, you may avoid giant lock but you need use ConcurrentHashMap or implement your version.

Some Notice:

- If you use two lists which are shared by different threads to maintain, you still need giant lock on them, otherwise will crash it.
- You will increment count of connection in order to compare with max permissible connections, which also need synchronization.

Some suggestions:

- Use atomic integer as counter
- Use ConcurrentHashMap or implement your version (actually it's like a array add linkedlist and the array element is the lock of list which avoid the giant lock)

Comment: Agreed with most of the points.  But what will be  the `key and value` in `HashMap`  in your suggested solution ?

Comment: key can be number of `Thread`, value is a list of connections. When a thread try to fetch a connection, it can mod the hashcode to get the key then get a connection from list.